# PHP - preg_replace - html tags and attributes

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to allow some tags and attributes using an array, and remove the rest

here is my example:

```
$allowed=array("img", "p", "style");
$text='<img src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()" style="background:red" onclick="myFunction()">

<p>A function is triggered if an error occurs when loading the image. The function shows an alert box with a text.
In this example we refer to an image that does not exist, therefore the onerror event occurs.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert(\'The image could not be loaded.\');
}
</script>';
```

using `$text= preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $text);`
I could remove script tag with content, but I need to remove everything not in `$allowed` array

Comment: You can use this HTML minifier I wrote, with a little work it could be made to remove specific tags.  It has the ability to not minify specific tags.  So you could change that to removing them (probably) https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/HtmlMinifier.php  It uses regex in a Lexer/Parser type of way.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` should not be used in production environments, might want to add a comment to that GIT.

Comment: It's not really meant to be production code, it was actually for another answer on here.  That's why its in MISC. and it does say `//For debugging`

Comment: Are there any nested tags? e.g. `<div><p>text</p><img />more text<p>text</p></div>`

Comment: Yes, the content is from text editor

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using DOMParser for better readability if you are mixing scripts with html altogether like this, take care about the performance if performance matters.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

This function should do what you want. Given a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) (`$doc`) and a node (`$node`) to search from, it recursively iterates over the children of that node, removing any tags that are not in the `$allowed_tags` array, and, for those tags that are kept, removing any attributes not in the `$allowed_attributes` array:

```
function remove_nodes_and_attributes($doc, $node, $allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    foreach ($xpath->query('./*', $node) as $child) {
        if (!in_array($child->nodeName, $allowed_tags)) {
            $node->removeChild($child);
            continue;
        }
        $a = 0;
        while ($a < $child->attributes->length) {
            $attribute = $child->attributes->item($a)->name;
            if (!in_array($attribute, $allowed_attributes)) {
                $child->removeAttribute($attribute);
                // don't increment the pointer as the list will shift with the removal of the attribute
            }
            else {
                // allowed attribute, skip it
                $a++;
            }
        }
        // remove any children as necessary
        remove_nodes_and_attributes($doc, $child, $allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes);
    }
}
```

You would use this function like this. Note it is necessary to wrap the HTML in a top-level element which is then stripped off again at the end using `substr`.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html>$text</html>", LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$html = $doc->getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
remove_nodes_and_attributes($doc, $html, $allowed_tags, $allowed_attributes);
echo substr($doc->saveHTML(), 6, -8);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
<img style="background:red">
<p>A function is triggered if an error occurs when loading the image. The function shows an alert box with a text. In this example we refer to an image that does not exist, therefore the onerror event occurs.</p>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vmSDF)

Answer (score 0):

Using DOMDocument is always the best way to manipulate HTML, it understands the structure of the document.

In this solution I use XPath to find any nodes which are not in the allowed list, the XPath expression will look something like...

```
//body//*[not(name() = "img" or name() = "p" or name() = "style")]
```

This looks for any element in the `<body>` tag (`loadHTML` will automatically put this tag in for you) who's name isn't in the list of allowed tags.  The XPath is built dynamically from the `$allowed` list and so you just change the list of tags to update it...

```
$allowed=array("img", "p", "style");
$text='<img src="image.gif" onerror="myFunction()" style="background:red" onclick="myFunction()">

<p>A function is triggered if an error occurs when loading the image. The function shows an alert box with a text.
In this example we refer to an image that does not exist, therefore the onerror event occurs.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert(\'The image could not be loaded.\');
}
</script>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$find = '//body//*[not(name() = "'.implode ('" or name() = "', $allowed ).
    '")]';
echo "XPath = ".$find.PHP_EOL;
$toRemove = $xp->evaluate($find);
print_r($toRemove);
foreach ( $toRemove as $remove )    {
    $remove->parentNode->removeChild($remove);
}

// recreate HTML
$outHTML = "";
foreach ( $doc->getElementsByTagName("body")[0]->childNodes as $tag )  {
    $outHTML.= $doc->saveHTML($tag);
}
echo $outHTML;
```

If you also want to remove attributes, you can do the same process using `@*` as part of the XPath expression...

```
$allowedAttribs = array();

$find = '//body//@*[not(name() = "'.implode ('" or name() = "', $allowedAttribs ).
'")]';
$toRemove = $xp->evaluate($find);
foreach ( $toRemove as $remove ) {
    $remove->parentNode->removeAttribute($remove->nodeName);
}
```

It would be possible to combine these two, but it makes the code less legible (IMHO).

Comment: This doesn't remove the attributes (`src`, `onclick` and `onerror`) from the `img` tag: https://3v4l.org/1RR3A

Comment: @Nick - I've added this.  Would be interesting if they want certain attributes from certain element types - or should I not mention that :-/

Comment: I think it's always safest not to ask that type of question, you just might get an answer! :-)